# Declaring User Control in page, Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can a user control be added to a page in Windows Phone 7 development?
I have the user control but I can't add it to a page....

Visual Studio doesn't support drag and drop to the canvas and I can't figure out how to declare it manually in the xaml.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage> 

<Views:MyUserControl />

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What's Views?

Comment: I figured it out. First, xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Mynamespace". Then, uc:MyControl.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, Views happened to be the directory I created the UC in.